# SQL Query,how to write a query that queries based on filter(date) + condition(status)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i am trying to query failed  jobs from a table that contains jobs information

Lets say its a backup jobs table (backupInfoTable) (simplifies the question)

```
jobName  | instanceName | status | date
________________________________________
one    |first instance| failed    | 12/16/2017
one    |first instance| success   | 1/1/2017
one    |secondInstance| failed    | 1/1/2017
one    |third instance| success   | 12/14/2017
two    |first instance| success   | 1/1/2017
two    |first instance| failed    | 1/1/2016
three  |first instance| failed    | 12/14/2017
```

i would like to query only the records where the most recent backup is a failed backup. 
if the most recent backup is a success, its not relevant and the query should ignore it.

for example the query result should be:

```
one    |first instance| failed    | 12/16/2017
one    |secondInstance| failed    | 1/1/2017
three  |first instance| failed    | 12/14/2017
```

thanks !

Answer (score 12):

> i would like to query only the records where the most recent backup is a failed backup.

Something like:

```
with q as
(
    select jobName, instanceName, jobStatus, date,
           row_number() over (partition by jobName, instanceName order by date desc) rn
    from backupInfotable
)
select jobName, instanceName, jobStatus, date
from q
where rn = 1 
  and jobStatus = 'failed'
```